# Como comparar MySQL com um array?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho que fazer uma comparação `MySQL` com um array de números.

**Por exemplo:**

Tenho um `array` de inteiros assm:

```
$inteiros = array();
```

E tenho que retornar os `ids` da minha tabela turma com esse `array`, assim:

```
SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE idTurma = (AQUI ENTRA O ARRAY);
```

Existe a possibilidade de fazer essa comparação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função `implode()` para transformar o array em uma string delimitada por vírgulas, isso vai na clásula `IN`

```
$inteiro = array(10,3,12);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM turma WHERE idTurma IN('. implode($inteiros, ',') .')';
```

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use IN.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
          FROM `table` 
         WHERE `id` IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $array)) . ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

Resposta tirada do [***SOEn***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722827/6797930) se o seu código for com [***PDO***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$inteiros = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IN ($qMarks)");
$sth->execute($inteiros);
```