# Query com array retornando apenas primeiro registo

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo, select

Tenho a as seguintes querys:

```
   <?php 

   $VarMensagem = 1;

   $pdo     = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd, $opt);
   $data          = array();
   $dataGeral     = array();

   try {
      $stmt    = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM mensagem WHERE mensagem_id ='{$VarMensagem}'");

      while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))

      {


         $data[] = $row;

           $VarMinhasResp   =  $data[]=$row->respostas;



      $QueryRespostas    = $pdo->query("SELECT id AS ID,descricao AS DESCRICAO FROM respostas WHERE id IN ('{$VarMinhasResp}')");

      while($row  = $QueryRespostas->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      {

         $dataGeral['respostas'] = $row;

         }


      }


$result = array_merge($data , $dataGeral);



echo json_encode($result);



   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

O que faço , vou na tabela mensagens e pego os id das respostas e faço uma consulta nas respostas, esta funcionando,mais esta retornando apenas o primeiro registro,segue como é o certo da consulta e que roda perfeitamente no mysql:

```
SELECT id AS ID,descricao AS DESCRICAO FROM respostas WHERE id IN (1,5,10,11,15)
```

Não consigo ver onde é o erro, se esta no loop ou nos array, o que pode ser ?

Comment: Por quê está executando a *query* dentro do `while`? Não deveria ser fora?

Comment: Tem vários erros, eles não estão separados por `,` e a execução está dentro do `while`. Além disso você pode [nem precisar do PHP para fazer isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189552/15089).

Comment: @ Anderson Carlos Woss Testei fora e também não foi

Comment: @ Inkeliz  Fiz como vc disse somente com sql e ainda assim retornou apenas o primeiro registro

Comment: `$dataGeral['respostas'] = $row;` você está atribuindo o valor na mesma variável a cada volta do loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você realmente quer utilizar o PHP para criar o `IN`, pode utilizar o `fetchAll` e utilizar o `implode` para juntar tudo.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT respostas FROM mensagem WHERE mensagem_id ='{$VarMensagem}'");

$idResposta = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$idResposta = implode(',', $idResultante);

$QueryRespostas = $pdo->query("SELECT id AS ID, descricao AS DESCRICAO FROM respostas WHERE id IN ('{$idResposta}')");

echo json_encode(['respostas' => $QueryRespostas->fetchAll()]);
```

A ideia é básica, como [mencionado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157698/15089) e [também aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177564/como-fazer-um-select-com-uma-array/177568#177568), basta adicionar `,` entre os elementos, dessa forma ficaria `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Depois utiliza tais dados para o `IN`.

---

Uma outra solução, mantendo o seu código *como está*:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM mensagem WHERE mensagem_id ='{$VarMensagem}'");

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $data[] = $row;

}

$VarMinhasResp = implode(',', array_column($data, 'respostas'));

$QueryRespostas = $pdo->query("SELECT id AS ID,descricao AS DESCRICAO FROM respostas WHERE id IN ('{$VarMinhasResp}')");

while($row = $QueryRespostas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $dataGeral['respostas'][] = $row;

}

$result = array_merge($data , $dataGeral);

echo json_encode($result);
```

---

Somente com SQL:

```
SELECT id        AS ID, 
       descricao AS DESCRICAO 
FROM   respostas 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT respostas
              FROM   mensagem 
              WHERE  mensagem_id = '{$VarMensagem}')
```

Dessa forma poderá fazer:

```
$QueryRespostas = $pdo->query("SELECT id AS ID, descricao AS DESCRICAO FROM respostas WHERE id IN(SELECT respostas FROM mensagem WHERE mensagem_id = '{$VarMensagem}')");
```